# Does python have something like pointer in C programming language?

Tags: python, pointers

I tried searching for this on the internet but I was unable to find a good answer.  Someone said `id()` returns a memory address but someone else says `id()` is not for memory addresses.

In the C programming language, there is a pointer to show the memory address, but I don't know how Python works in such cases.

Can anyone give me some help to understand how Python saves data in memory?

Comment: Are there no pointers? Or are all variables pointers? It depends what exact definition of pointer you are using.

Comment: if you pass a list inside your function, and edit it, it will be edited outside two. One might call this behaviour pointer like.

Comment: How do you define "ideal answer", i.e. what makes it ideal?

Comment: I think you should do some more research before posting. You need to show effort.

Comment: @khelwood Even for constant True/False is python object.  every python object has its own id(). There is no pointer for the python programming language but id(). And in the CPython interpreter, it uses the value of C pointer as id() for every python object.

Comment: It looks like this question was edited to try and better suit the answer that was posted to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a popular question for people who learn python.

The answer is that **python has no pointer but using id(). And id() return C language memory address in CPython interpreter.**

Everything in python is a python object and id() is the identity of the python object. When you write python code you need to understand how id() works, or you will waste many memory spaces. By the way, the following picture shows some real examples of how id() work in python.
[image]

In the CPython interpreter, the id() returns the C memory address value of PyObject. Everything in python is a python object even for the True/False value.
The description of id() in python is

> *Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer that is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.*

There are many interpreters in Python and they can implement id(). We know the most popular one is CPython and its source code is here
https://github.com/python/cpython

And the source code to implement id() is here
[image]

CPython is the interpreter in C. In the source code, every python object is PyObject in C and the id() will return the C memory address of this PyObject. But remember that does not mean the interpreter should return memory address for id(). It's just CPython interpreter do it and it is satisfied with the specification of python.

So, that's why I say python has no pointer but id(). And CPython interpreter returns the C memory address of PyObject as the value of id().

Comment: It is not clear how the existence or behaviour of the id function is supposed to resolve the OP's uncertainty about pointers.

Comment: Hi @khelwood, Thanks for your reply. 
What do you mean when you say "OP's uncertainty"?  What is OP you said here?

Comment: OP means "original poster": the person who asked the question.

Comment: @khelwood 
In the start of this answer, it say 
The answer is that python has no pointer but using id(). And id() return C language memory address in CPython interpreter.  that's the key to answer this question. :)